# Not able to parse json in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "complete": 1,
    "list": {
        "378144457": {
            "item_id": "378144457",
            "resolved_id": "378144457",
            "given_url": "https://ngrok.com",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1372274736",
            "time_updated": "1372274741",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 3,
            "resolved_title": "Introspected tunnels to localhost",
            "resolved_url": "https://ngrok.com",
            "excerpt": "ngrok creates a tunnel from the public internet (http://subdomain.ngrok.com) to a port on your local machine. You can give this URL to anyone to allow them to try out a web site you're developing without doing any deployment.  ngrok captures all traffic through the tunnel.",
            "is_article": "0",
            "is_index": "1",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "422"
        },
        "380099389": {
            "item_id": "380099389",
            "resolved_id": "380099389",
            "given_url": "http://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/69",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1371518628",
            "time_updated": "1371518632",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 5,
            "resolved_title": "Viewpoint: New Particle Hints at Four-Quark Matter",
            "resolved_url": "http://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/69",
            "excerpt": "Particle physicists seem to have a pretty good handle on the fundamental particles of the universe, but there are some glaring holes in this understanding. Quarks are a good example of this.",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "1053"
        },
        "385567551": {
            "item_id": "385567551",
            "resolved_id": "385567551",
            "given_url": "http://gtrak.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/clojure-tradeoffs/",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1372794240",
            "time_updated": "1372794247",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 0,
            "resolved_title": "Clojure Tradeoffs (design implications and why you should care)",
            "resolved_url": "http://gtrak.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/clojure-tradeoffs/",
            "excerpt": "Clojure as a language and community is very sensitive to the definition and design of tradeoffs. This post is an attempt to elucidate the tradeoffs chosen by the language, what they mean to interested parties, and an attempt to predict the future based on these choices.",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "0",
            "word_count": "2568"
        },
        "385823467": {
            "item_id": "385823467",
            "resolved_id": "385823467",
            "given_url": "http://devo.ps/blog/2013/06/26/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2.html",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1372275849",
            "time_updated": "1372275853",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 2,
            "resolved_title": "Goodbye node-forever, hello PM2",
            "resolved_url": "http://devo.ps/blog/2013/06/26/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2.html",
            "excerpt": "It’s no secret that the devo.ps team has a crush on Javascript; node.js in the backend, AngularJS for our clients, there isn’t much of our stack that isn’t at least in part built with it. Our approach of building static clients and RESTful JSON APIs means that we run a lot of node.",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "800"
        },
        "386086417": {
            "item_id": "386086417",
            "resolved_id": "386086417",
            "given_url": "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5946900",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1372274365",
            "time_updated": "1372274367",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 4,
            "resolved_title": "Richard Stallman Inducted Into the 2013 Internet Hall of Fame",
            "resolved_url": "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5946900",
            "excerpt": "The man never misses an opportunity to try and get people thinking about the issues that matter.  I'm unconvinced. The majority of people are sharing more about themselves online. Not less.",
            "is_article": "0",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "0",
            "word_count": "2316"
        },
        "388862014": {
            "item_id": "388862014",
            "resolved_id": "388862014",
            "given_url": "http://imgur.com/a/Op82P",
            "given_title": "",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1372692033",
            "time_updated": "1372692040",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 1,
            "resolved_title": "Upload images",
            "resolved_url": "http://imgur.com/a/Op82P",
            "excerpt": "",
            "is_article": "0",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "2",
            "word_count": "0"
        }
    },
    "since": 1372879049
}
```

I'm trying to parse this json in Javascript but failing miserably in node.

```
 data = JSON.parse(body); //body is the json response
 dat = data["list"];
```

I get the list from here but how do I parse this? 
     JSON.stringify(dat) doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmm. Seems to be invalid JSON according to [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) (parse error on line 40)

Comment: @CrazyTrain Updated the question with valid JSON.

Comment: data["list"] returns an object.  What do you want to do with that object, specifically?

Comment: @NickTomlin I want the "given_url".

Comment: It should already be parsed... What does `data["list"]["380099389"]["given_url"]` give you?

Comment: That works. But how would I know that the id is 380099389? I mean, the list will be longer, and I'm not able to parse through it.

Comment: Again, what do you want to do with this data? Do you want to retrieve ALL "given_url" values, or one specific value?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ALl the given url values. Basically I want to retrieve all the urls in each of the ids that are given as numbers such as 380099389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `for in` loop like this:

```
for (var id in data["list"]){
    console.log(id + " has given_url " +data["list"][id]["given_url"]);
}
```

If you are using a library that modifies the base Object prototype you may also need a `hasOwnProperty` check like this:

```
for (var id in data["list"]){
    if (data["list"].hasOwnProperty(id)){
        console.log(id + " has given_url " +data["list"][id]["given_url"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That worked. Thank you so much. This seems like Pythony solution. I tried forEach but always gave errors. Thank you again.

Comment: @Hick: Just FYI, `.forEach()` is for Arrays. To use it on plain objects, you can get an Array of object keys, and then iterate that Array, using each key to access the object, like: `Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(key) { console.log(key, data.list[key].given_url); });`